# mktime conversion

Tags: c, mktime

I wanted to calculate the time difference for a GMT time and current time. For this I am converting tm time  (which is in GMT) to time_t format using mktime. and current time using time() api.

```
struct tm = x;  time_t t1, t2; 
time(&t1);
/* here x  will get in GMT format */
t2 = mktime(&x);
sec = difftime(t2 , t1);
```

In this for making the same time zone, is mktime() will  take care of converting to local time ? or shall I need to explicitly add  `sec = difftime(t2 , gmtime(&t1);`
Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to accept any answers.  Why should anyone bother to help you?

Comment: what trojanfoe politely wants to say is, you should take a look over the answers to your 8 questions, and mark those, which helped you, as "accepted answer".

Comment: I am waiting for the answer. I wanted to know whether mktime() is internally converting to local time().

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to accept the answer. I haven't seen any link for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `mktime` convert to local time, please read the man:

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/mktime.3.asp

```
mktime() : convert local time to seconds since the Epoch
```

**EDIT** : To calculate the difference time between two dates, you can use this

```
    time_t t1, t2;
    struct tm my_target_date;

    /* Construct your date */
    my_target_date.tm_sec = 0;
    my_target_date.tm_min = 0;
    my_target_date.tm_hour = 0;
    my_target_date.tm_mday = 20;
    my_target_date.tm_mon = 7;
    my_target_date.tm_year = 112; /* Date today */
    t1 = mktime (&my_target_date);
    t2 = time (NULL);
    printf ("Number of days since target date : %ld\n", (t2 - t1) / 86400); /* 1 day = 86400 sec, use 3600 if you want hours */
```

Comment: Hence no need to explicitly convert from GMT to local time or localtime to gmtime(). So I can use the first price of code. Am I right?

Comment: @user1345697 : yes (the man page clearly say that the diff time is using local time), i will post sample code and you can test by your self to see if that's ok or not.

Comment: @user1345697 : if the answer is OK for you can accept it (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), think ato accept other answers for other people who helped you in the past